# Swift: Possible logic error

Tags: swift, logic

I am trying to create a simple tic tac toe game. No AI needed. I have gotten to the point that I can click the buttons in my UI and they will switch each time. I also created a checkScore() function. However, I think that my checkScore() function has bad logic somewhere and I have spent two days trying to figure it out. If the user gets three in a row it should run the winnerMessage() function for where ever the win was. My variable names are pretty self explanatory.

My issue here is that unless I comment out all of the "else if" statements in the checkScore() function the winnerMessage runs upon the first click of the board. Please help! Thanks.

Defining the variables.

```
    var player1 = "❌"
    var player2 = "⭕️"
    var currentPlayer = "❌"

    let originalValue = ""

    let winnerMessageTopHorizontal = "We have a winner across the top!"
    let winnerMessageCenterHorizontal = "We have a winner across the  center!"
    let winnerMessageBottomHorizontal = "We have a winner across the bottom!"
    let winnerMessageLeftVertical = "We have a winner on the left side!"
    let winnerMessageCenterVertical = "We have a winner down the center!"
    let winnerMessageRightVertical = "We have a winner on the right side!"
    let winnerMessageDiagonal1 = "We have a winner diagonally!"
    let winnerMessageDiagonal2 = "We have a winner diagonally!"
```

This is the changePlayer() function that I created.

```
/* function that changes from player1 to player2 (switching from X to O and O to X)*/
    func changePlayer(){

        if currentPlayer == player1{
            print ("\(player1)")
            currentPlayer = player2
        }



        else if currentPlayer == player2{
            print ("\(player2)")
            currentPlayer = player1
        }


        else{
            NSLog ("Error. Please reset the game.")
        }

    }
```

This is the checkScore() function that I keep having problems with. If you comment out all lines of the function except for the first one then you can see that the first step works how it is supposed to.

```
func checkScore(){



   if topLeftOutlet.currentTitle == topCenterOutlet.currentTitle && topLeftOutlet.currentTitle == topRightOutlet.currentTitle && topLeftOutlet.currentTitle != ""{
            announcementArea.text = winnerMessageTopHorizontal
        }

        else if leftCenterOutlet.currentTitle == centerOutlet.currentTitle && leftCenterOutlet.currentTitle == rightCenterOutlet.currentTitle && leftCenterOutlet.currentTitle != ""{
            announcementArea.text = winnerMessageCenterHorizontal
        }
        else if bottomLeftOutlet.currentTitle == bottomCenterOutlet.currentTitle && bottomLeftOutlet.currentTitle == bottomRightOutlet.currentTitle && bottomLeftOutlet.currentTitle != ""{
            announcementArea.text = winnerMessageBottomHorizontal
        }
        else if topLeftOutlet.currentTitle == leftCenterOutlet.currentTitle && topLeftOutlet.currentTitle == bottomLeftOutlet.currentTitle && topLeftOutlet.currentTitle != ""{
            announcementArea.text = winnerMessageLeftVertical
        }
        else if topCenterOutlet.currentTitle == centerOutlet.currentTitle && topCenterOutlet.currentTitle == bottomCenterOutlet.currentTitle && topCenterOutlet.currentTitle != ""{
            announcementArea.text = winnerMessageCenterVertical
        }
        else if topRightOutlet.currentTitle == rightCenterOutlet.currentTitle && topRightOutlet.currentTitle == bottomRightOutlet.currentTitle && topRightOutlet.currentTitle != ""{
            announcementArea.text = winnerMessageRightVertical
        }
        else if topLeftOutlet.currentTitle == centerOutlet.currentTitle && topLeftOutlet.currentTitle == bottomRightOutlet.currentTitle && topLeftOutlet.currentTitle != ""{
            announcementArea.text = winnerMessageDiagonal1
        }
        else if topRightOutlet.currentTitle == centerOutlet.currentTitle && topRightOutlet.currentTitle == bottomLeftOutlet.currentTitle && topLeftOutlet.currentTitle != ""{
            announcementArea.text = winnerMessageDiagonal2
        }

        else{
            NSLog ("Keep going")
        }




    }
     @IBOutlet weak var announcementArea: UITextField!
```

Action and Outlets for the buttons on the board. The Actions are when the user clicks the button it will change to either X or O. The outlets are for the reset function below that resets the values to empty.

```
    @IBAction func topLeft(sender: UIButton) {
        sender.setTitle(currentPlayer, forState: .Normal)
        changePlayer()
        checkScore()
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var topLeftOutlet: UIButton!

    @IBAction func topCenter(sender: UIButton) {
        sender.setTitle(currentPlayer, forState: .Normal)
        changePlayer()
        checkScore()
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var topCenterOutlet: UIButton!

    @IBAction func topRight(sender: UIButton) {
        sender.setTitle(currentPlayer, forState: .Normal)
        changePlayer()
        checkScore()
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var topRightOutlet: UIButton!

    @IBAction func leftCenter(sender: UIButton) {
        sender.setTitle(currentPlayer, forState: .Normal)
        changePlayer()
        checkScore()
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var leftCenterOutlet: UIButton!

    @IBAction func center(sender: UIButton) {
        sender.setTitle(currentPlayer, forState: .Normal)
        changePlayer()
        checkScore()
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var centerOutlet: UIButton!

    @IBAction func rightCenter(sender: UIButton) {
        sender.setTitle(currentPlayer, forState: .Normal)
        changePlayer()
        checkScore()
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var rightCenterOutlet: UIButton!

    @IBAction func bottomLeft(sender: UIButton) {
        sender.setTitle(currentPlayer, forState: .Normal)
        changePlayer()
        checkScore()
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var bottomLeftOutlet: UIButton!

    @IBAction func bottomCenter(sender: UIButton) {
        sender.setTitle(currentPlayer, forState: .Normal)
        changePlayer()
        checkScore()
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var bottomCenterOutlet: UIButton!

    @IBAction func bottomRight(sender: UIButton) {
        sender.setTitle(currentPlayer, forState: .Normal)
        changePlayer()
        checkScore()
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var bottomRightOutlet: UIButton!
```

This button is currently useless:

```
    @IBAction func startGame(sender: UIButton) {
        NSLog ("Player Started Game")
    }
```

resetButton() function that resets the board when the player clicks the reset button

```
    @IBAction func resetGame(sender: UIButton) {
        NSLog ("Player Reset Game")
        topLeftOutlet.setTitle(originalValue, forState: .Normal)
        topCenterOutlet.setTitle(originalValue, forState: .Normal)
        topRightOutlet.setTitle(originalValue, forState: .Normal)
        leftCenterOutlet.setTitle(originalValue, forState: .Normal)
        centerOutlet.setTitle(originalValue, forState: .Normal)
        rightCenterOutlet.setTitle(originalValue, forState: .Normal)
        bottomLeftOutlet.setTitle(originalValue, forState: .Normal)
        bottomCenterOutlet.setTitle(originalValue, forState: .Normal)
        bottomRightOutlet.setTitle(originalValue, forState: .Normal)
    }


}
```

Thank you so much for taking a look. I don't expect it to be perfect. I just need another eye to see if I missed something obvious!

Comment: FYI - you can use a single button action to handle every button since all of the code in your 9 existing button handlers are all the same. But this isn't related to your issue. Just a suggestion.

Comment: When your `checkScore` method is called, which line mistakenly announces a winner? Use the debugger and step through line by line and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! The second line of the checkScore() function being introduced will cause a click of any button to result in displaying a winnerMessage in the text field @IBOutlet weak var announcementArea: UITextField!

Comment: Look at your last `else if` clause in `checkScore()` and look at which buttons it is checking.

Answer (score 0):

i figure out your problem.Problem was in changeScore method where your buttons contains nil value in starting but you compare them with "" string that's why every time your condition become always true and display winner Message.you just need to replace all you condition of != "" with != nil like this

```
   if topLeftOutlet.currentTitle == topCenterOutlet.currentTitle && topLeftOutlet.currentTitle == topRightOutlet.currentTitle && topLeftOutlet.currentTitle != nil{
        announcementArea.text = winnerMessageTopHorizontal
    }

    else if leftCenterOutlet.currentTitle == centerOutlet.currentTitle && leftCenterOutlet.currentTitle == rightCenterOutlet.currentTitle && leftCenterOutlet.currentTitle != nil{
        announcementArea.text = winnerMessageCenterHorizontal
    }
    else if bottomLeftOutlet.currentTitle == bottomCenterOutlet.currentTitle && bottomLeftOutlet.currentTitle == bottomRightOutlet.currentTitle && bottomLeftOutlet.currentTitle != nil{
        announcementArea.text = winnerMessageBottomHorizontal
    }
    else if topLeftOutlet.currentTitle == leftCenterOutlet.currentTitle && topLeftOutlet.currentTitle == bottomLeftOutlet.currentTitle && topLeftOutlet.currentTitle != nil{
        announcementArea.text = winnerMessageLeftVertical
    }
    else if topCenterOutlet.currentTitle == centerOutlet.currentTitle && topCenterOutlet.currentTitle == bottomCenterOutlet.currentTitle && topCenterOutlet.currentTitle != nil{
        announcementArea.text = winnerMessageCenterVertical
    }
    else if topRightOutlet.currentTitle == rightCenterOutlet.currentTitle && topRightOutlet.currentTitle == bottomRightOutlet.currentTitle && topRightOutlet.currentTitle != nil{
        announcementArea.text = winnerMessageRightVertical
    }
    else if topLeftOutlet.currentTitle == centerOutlet.currentTitle && topLeftOutlet.currentTitle == bottomRightOutlet.currentTitle && topLeftOutlet.currentTitle != nil{
        announcementArea.text = winnerMessageDiagonal1
    }
    else if topRightOutlet.currentTitle == centerOutlet.currentTitle && topRightOutlet.currentTitle == bottomLeftOutlet.currentTitle && topLeftOutlet.currentTitle != nil{
        announcementArea.text = winnerMessageDiagonal2
    }

    else{
        NSLog ("Keep going")
    }
```

Also set nil in button title in you reset method. 
i hope it will resolve your issue

Answer (score 0):

The answer that Sumit gave me was part of the solution. Thanks for getting me in the right direction! The way to make it work was that the checkScore() function needs to be written like this:

```
    func checkScore(){

    if (topLeftOutlet.currentTitle == topCenterOutlet.currentTitle && topLeftOutlet.currentTitle == topRightOutlet.currentTitle && topLeftOutlet.currentTitle != originalValue && topLeftOutlet.currentTitle != nil){

        announcementArea.text = winnerMessageTopHorizontal

     }

    if (leftCenterOutlet.currentTitle == centerOutlet.currentTitle && centerOutlet.currentTitle == rightCenterOutlet.currentTitle && leftCenterOutlet.currentTitle != originalValue && leftCenterOutlet.currentTitle != nil) {

        announcementArea.text = winnerMessageCenterHorizontal

     }

     if (bottomLeftOutlet.currentTitle == bottomCenterOutlet.currentTitle && bottomLeftOutlet.currentTitle == bottomRightOutlet.currentTitle && bottomLeftOutlet.currentTitle != originalValue && bottomLeftOutlet.currentTitle != nil){

        announcementArea.text = winnerMessageBottomHorizontal
     }

     if (topLeftOutlet.currentTitle == leftCenterOutlet.currentTitle && topLeftOutlet.currentTitle == bottomLeftOutlet.currentTitle && topLeftOutlet != originalValue && topLeftOutlet.currentTitle != nil){

        announcementArea.text = winnerMessageLeftVertical
     }

     if (topCenterOutlet.currentTitle == centerOutlet.currentTitle && topCenterOutlet.currentTitle == bottomCenterOutlet.currentTitle && topCenterOutlet.currentTitle != originalValue && topCenterOutlet.currentTitle != nil){

        announcementArea.text = winnerMessageCenterVertical
     }

     if (topRightOutlet.currentTitle == rightCenterOutlet.currentTitle && topRightOutlet.currentTitle == bottomRightOutlet.currentTitle && topRightOutlet.currentTitle != originalValue && topRightOutlet.currentTitle != nil){

        announcementArea.text = winnerMessageRightVertical
     }

     if (topLeftOutlet.currentTitle == centerOutlet.currentTitle && topLeftOutlet.currentTitle == bottomRightOutlet.currentTitle && topLeftOutlet.currentTitle != originalValue && topLeftOutlet.currentTitle != nil){

        announcementArea.text = winnerMessageDiagonal1
     }

     if (topRightOutlet.currentTitle == centerOutlet.currentTitle && topRightOutlet.currentTitle == bottomLeftOutlet.currentTitle && topRightOutlet.currentTitle != originalValue && topRightOutlet.currentTitle != nil){

        announcementArea.text = winnerMessageDiagonal2
     }
}
```

Each "if" statement needs to check that the button title is not equal to originalValue which is an empty string variable that I created. Also, like Sumit mentioned, it needs to check that the button title is not equal to nil.

Comment: i don't understand why you don't want to use else if statements.

Comment: i don't think my answer is part of solution ,it's exactly an correct answer